# How to publish application update on app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, publish

I have to publish first update for my publish application. I want to do it right, but have no idea how :( Any help please?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to upload your project to the appstore?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do just like you would when creating the application initially. Only difference is that once you have created your new build (with higher version number string in the plist) in Xcode and you are in iTunes Connect, instead of clicking 'Add New Application' in the 'Manage Your Applications' tab, you'll go into the application you are updating and clicking 'Add Version'.

Answer (score 5):

You login to iTunes Connect and create a new version of your Application.

It asks you for changes you made in the update.

Then you upload the binary and wait for the review.

Simple as that...